# TLS 1.2 support which java version?

Tags: tls1.2

I would like to check which minimum versions of Java is needed (including patch level) to support TLS 1.2.

Required all the documents couldn't find exact compatibility matrix. Need your help.

Comment: Verified all the documents couldn't find exact compatibility matrix. Need your help

Comment: Java 7 and above definitely support it. I think you can make 6 do it as well.  See this: https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7